# Is there any shortkey to insert the commenter name in a new comment?

Tags: support, comments, comment-replies

When I comment is some question or answer in this including all SE sites I noticed that it shows suggestion if I start with `@`.

But, it is boring to me to use mouse to select the commenter's name.

Is there any short key to insert the name?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key to switch between possible suggestions which should auto-complete the full @-mention.

[image]

For more details on @-replies, see [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/168244)

Comment: doesn't work...